# How to use check button in python tkinter to show or hide text in the Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on an encryption project.if i want to insert a radio button that when checked shows the text in the Entry widget as '*' and shows the text as it is when unchecked . How can i do that in python .

assume my entry widget name = text_entry.

Comment: Are you able to show us what attempts you have made to stop us going over ground that you have already covered?

Comment: What research have you done? What part of the problem do you need help with? Do you know how to configure an entry widget to show only asterisks? Do you know how to create radiobuttons? Do you know how to attach callbacks to radiobuttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `show` attribute of the Entry widget.

If show is not set or equal to `""` then regular text will show in the field. If you change it to equal `"*"` then you will see asterisk.

This can be toggled using a method/function to change that attribute.

Take a look at the below code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        self.text_entry = tk.Entry(self, show = "*")
        self.text_entry.pack()
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="Toggle asterisk", command = self.toggle)
        self.btn1.pack()

    def toggle(self):
        if self.text_entry["show"] == "":
            self.text_entry["show"] = "*"

        else:
            self.text_entry["show"] = ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    Example().pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

My example specifically uses a button to toggle the asterisk and not a Check Button or a Radio Button because you have not shown any code yourself and I just wanted to point you in the right direction rather than write all the code for you.

You should be able to take the relevant parts from my example and tie them into the use of a Check Button or a Radio Button.